# Django - Changed DB from Sqlite3 to Postgres - do I need to do something else to reflect changes?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, psycopg2

In my server, I changed the DB to Postgres from SQlite3. Because this is a new website and doesn't have much data yet (except test stuff) I didn't have to do DB migration or whatever else it is called. I just changed `settings.DATABASES` to include Postgres. Here's my `settings.DATABASES` in `settings.py`:

```
from sys import platform
if platform == 'darwin':  # OSX
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR + '/db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'pfcbookclub',
            'USER': 'admin',
            'PASSWORD': 'g&zy8Je!u',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

I develop on an M1, and `psycopg2` doesn't seem to work for me, how many ever times I try to install `libq` or `openssl` with Homebrew on Rosetta, which is why I decided to use Sqlite on my Mac and Postgres on my server.

Now, when I pulled these changes with `git` onto my server, I refreshed the page on my domain, but all the test data I had filled in my Sqlite3 database still showed. I thought it would be empty because I haven't filled up the Postgres DB with anything and I didn't do any sort of migration that would convert `db.sqlite3` into Postgres thingy.

Is this what was supposed to happen? If so, why?

If that's not what's supposed to happen, I guess I must reload `gunicorn` or `daemon` or `nginx` or something else. What should I do? Why?

Comment: djano's dev-sever reloads changes on the fly, a proper web server does not.  I haven't used Django for a long time but I would generally restart both gunicorn and nginx (not sure what daemon is here, unless you mean should you do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?  - yes you should). I would  usually stop services from the outside in - first nginx, then gunicorn, and start from the inside out - first gunicorn, then nginx.

Comment: Yes I did mean `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: Great! I think the database finally changed! All the data's gone, but I don't mind, because it's all test stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Not so great. **Unexpected loss of data should always be a concern.** You better figure out why you lost your data, might not matter now, but eventually you will need a production run. You had better have a plan for the same thing happening when it does matter. Either know why and prevent it, or plan on recovery. Either way, make sure you have a backup ready.

Comment: Sure. I wouldn't have done this if this had any real users, as the website is set to launch on the 15th of Jan

Comment: Also, I lost the data because I changed the DB without migrating any of the data over. I heard it's a long and tedious process, but I'd do it, however hard it might be, if there was a user on the platform.